# Why do my desktop icons disappear on my Asus laptop?

Tags: windows-vista, laptop

I have an Asus laptop running Vista and the desktop icons sometimes spontaneously disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic167506.html

Asus's power management software seems to think displaying icons takes too much power, so switching from "Power4Gear Quiet Office" to "Power4Gear High Performance" brings them back.  Thanks, Asus.

Comment: "Asus's power management software seems to think displaying icons takes too much power"... wow. Just... wow. +1 for pity.

Comment: I know.  I saw the solution and said "that's just stupid."  Then it worked.  I was floored.